# Rectangular selection visual glitch

Tags: emacs

When I start a rectangular selection (<kbd>C-x SPS</kbd>), firstly, a thin line appears at the side of the rectangle which shifts lines to the right.

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to make rectangular selection seamless?

Comment: This looks to me like font weirdness. Please try `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Courier-10")` (or some other common default on your OS) and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thin line is put "on purpose" to visually show where is the empty rectangle.  We could make it optional (in which case the 0-width rectangles would simply not be displayed).  Please use `M-x report-emacs-bug` since that's where this discussion should take place.